# What does Google Picker API drivepreopen do?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-picker

I've noticed that some google drive apps fire POST request to https://docs.google.com/picker/drivepreopen?hostId=myhost upon file selection in picker dialog. Does anybody know what it does? 
I need to be able to access my google docs files from my google drive app and I'm aware of the fact that drive apps can access only files it created or opened via context menu in google drive. As the name "drivepreopen" suggests maybe it allows you to programmatically invoke "open with"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Picker is how your app should be given access to a file and it can be used to display a list of the currently authenticated user's Drive files, as explained at https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker.

Comment: thanks for answering but i've already read documentation and my problem is with [file access](https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview#granting_file-level_access). The question is what does drivepreopen do and how can i use it, it's not documented...

Comment: it is not documented because developers are not supposed to use it :)

Comment: Right) Could you please tell me why it might return `&&&START&&&{"response":[{"id":"DoclistBlob.0.0B98utCrSBDoZOTQ4NzExMDYtNjVmMy00ODc1LTgyM2UtOWQyY2M4MDhkZGMx","error":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}]}` when the same file is accessed with my app while it doesn't return PERMISSION_DENIED error when accessed with other apps?

Comment: What's the difference with the other apps? Can you please create another question with the code for the two apps (working and not working) and all details you have to help us reproduce it?